# Unable to convert the string date and time to format using Moment.JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i having a date format like  date = "20190516" and time like : "073000" and i am trying this to convert to normal date format using moment js but i am getting **NAN** error

```
let dat = "20190516"
let form = moment(dat).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
alert(form);

let dat = "073000"
let form = moment(dat).format('HH:MM:ss');
alert(form);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing time as string format and it is not in ISO 8601 you need define what format it is otherwise you will get a function deprecated warning from `moment.js`

If you do not define format type in your time in your case you need to add `HHmmss` Otherwise you will get this type of warning.

> **Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Read more about string types and dates here in [moment official docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

Run snippet below.

```js
let time = "073000"
let timeFormatted = moment(time, 'HHmmss').format('HH:mm:ss');
console.log('Time: '+ timeFormatted)

let date = "20190516"
let dateFormatted = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log('Date: '+ dateFormatted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**First Format**

```
const newFormat = moment('20190516','YYYYMMDD').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
alert(newFormat);
```

---

**Second Format**

```
const newFormat = moment('073000','HHmmss').format('HH:mm:ss');
alert(newFormat);
```

Comment: for time i tried the same  const Format = moment('071300','HHMMSS').format('HH:MM:SS');
console.log(Format);  but instead of 07:13 i am getting 07:01 as result

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Moment how to parse `073000` since it's not in ISO 8601 or RFC 2822 Date time format and it therefore can't infer it.

From the [moment documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, we then check if the string matches the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of new Date(string) if a known format is not found.

```
let dat = "20190516";
let form = moment(dat).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
alert(form);

let dat = moment("073000", "HHmmss");
let form = moment(dat).format("HH:mm:ss");
alert(form);
```

By the way, `MM` is used to format months whereas `mm` is used to format minutes.